# How to perform "Exact Match" in macOS or Finder smart search?

Tags: macos

Is there any way to perform exact match search in macOS? I want to search file that contains "Endorsement Number", but entering endorsement number as the search criteria shows me the list of file that contains endorsement and number in the result.

I want to find only the files that contain "Endorsement Number".

P.S. It doesn’t have to be case sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try searching for "Endorsement Number" with surrounding quotes?

[image]

I just tested this on my System (macOS Sierra 10.12.2), and a search for "Endorsement Number" (with quotes) returns files that contain "Endorsement Number" excatly, while files that only contain *Endorsement* or *Number* are not shown in the search results.

Answer (score 0):

"Endorsment Number" exact finder search highlights also contents like:

"Endorsment                 Number"

It looks that some special characters like spaces, are treated specially